# Length of feature-vector returned by 'extractLBPFeatures' for different size of images

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction

I have used `extractLBPFeatures` for feature extraction for 64*64 and 200*200 images.

```
a=imread('f1.jpg'); % f1.jpg is of size 64*64
b=extractLBPFeatures(a);
size(b)

ans =

     1    59
```

```
c = imresize(a, [200 200]); % a resized image.
d=extractLBPFeatures(c);
size(d)

ans =
    1    59
```

I have noticed, in both cases, it returns a vector of length 1*59 (`b` and `d` in the above code). Why is that?

Is there any way to reduce the number of length of vector? i.e. is there a way to reduce the number of parameters returned by `extractLBPFeatures`?  (I am aware that it might affect the classification task).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why is it 1x59 for both `a` and `c`?

From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extractlbpfeatures.html),

> LBP feature vector is returned as a 1-by-N vector of length `N` representing the number of features... The overall LBP feature length, `N`, depends on the number of cells and the number of bins, `B`:
>
> ```
> N = numCells x B
> ```

where, by default, we have:

‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ Cellsize equals size(I);  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍where I is the image
 ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ numCells = prod(floor(size(I)/CellSize));
⇒ numCells = 1

 ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ Number of neighbours = P = 8
 ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ B = (P × P–1) + 3
    ⇒ 
      B = 59

    ⇒ N = 1x59 (by default)

---

### Is there a way to reduce the number of parameters returned by `extractLBPFeatures`?

As shown by the above calculation, by reducing the [*number of neighbours*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extractlbpfeatures.html#input_argument_d0e125861), `P` , changing the [*Rotation invariance flag*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extractlbpfeatures.html#input_argument_d0e125931) and hence [*the number of bins*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extractlbpfeatures.html#output_argument_d0e126097), `B`, you can reduce that. But you should be sure what you're doing.

An example:

```
extractLBPFeatures(a,'Upright',false,'NumNeighbors',4);
```